# 'Failed to create a 'Type' from the text 's:MoveThumb'.'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

sorry if I repeat the topic. However none of the previous solution worked for me. I`ve tried to make a teplate for a ContentControl which would be generated automatically when a user pushes the button.

Xaml here:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="371" Width="556" Closing="Window_Closing" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
<Grid Height="325" Width="518">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="172*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="153*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <MediaElement Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="mediaElement1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="506" MediaOpened="mediaElement1_MediaOpened" Margin="0,30,0,0" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Stretch="None"/>
    <ListBox Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="359,151,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    <ListBox Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,151,368,0" Name="listBox2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    <Button Content="Browse" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="359,122,0,0" Name="Enviroment" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Enviroment_Click" />
    <Button Content="Enviroment" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,122,0,0" Name="Browse" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Browse_Click" />
    <Button Content="Play" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,79,0,0" Name="Play" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Play_Click" />
    <Button Content="Stop" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="245,79,0,0" Name="Stop" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Stop_Click" />
    <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,50,0,0" Name="slider1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="506" Thumb.DragStarted="slider1_DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="slider1_DragCompleted" MouseDown="slider1_MouseDown" />
    <Canvas Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="156,151,165,0" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="1" Background="White" OpacityMask="Black" Grid.RowSpan="2">

        <Canvas.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="MoveThumbTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type s:MoveThumb}">
                <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
            </ControlTemplate>

            <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate" TargetType="Control">
                <Grid>
                    <s:MoveThumb Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
    Cursor="SizeAll"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Canvas.Resources>

        <ContentControl Name="contentControl1" Width="26" Height="25" Canvas.Left="79" Canvas.Top="70" 
                        Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="86" Canvas.Top="70" Height="19" Name="ellipse1" Stroke="Black" Width="19" Fill="Red" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        </ContentControl>

        <ContentControl Name="contentControl2" Width="26" Height="26" Canvas.Left="140" Canvas.Top="26"
                        Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="140" Canvas.Top="33" Fill="#FF93FF14" Height="19" Name="ellipse2" Stroke="Black" Width="19" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        </ContentControl>


    </Canvas>
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,123,236,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="/ 200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,123,301,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="/ 162" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" />
    <TextBlock Height="22" Margin="156,123,334,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" Margin="0,123,257,0" Name="textBlock4" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="38" />
    <Button Content="Load" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="443,122,0,0" Name="Load" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Click="Load_Click" />
</Grid>
```

and the part of the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using rayav_csharp;
using System.Windows.Shapes;    
using System.Windows.Controls;  

using System.Windows.Media;     
using System.Windows.Markup;   

string template = "<ControlTemplate x:Key=\"MoveThumbTemplate\" TargetType=\"{x:Type s:MoveThumb}\">" +
                    "<Rectangle Fill=\"Transparent\"/>" +
                "</ControlTemplate>";
            ParserContext parser = new ParserContext();
            parser.XmlnsDictionary.Add("","http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
            parser.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x","http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
            parser.XmlnsDictionary.Add("s","clr-namespace:WpfApplication1");
            control.Template = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(template, parser);



public class MoveThumb : Thumb
    {
        public MoveThumb()
        {
            DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(this.MoveThumb_DragDelta);
        }

        private void MoveThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            Control item = this.DataContext as Control;

            if (item != null)
            {
                double left = Canvas.GetLeft(item);
                double top = Canvas.GetTop(item);

                Canvas.SetLeft(item, left + e.HorizontalChange);
                Canvas.SetTop(item, top + e.VerticalChange);
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone can help?
Greetings

Comment: Any inner exception?

Comment: Exception:Thrown: "Type reference cannot find type named '{clr-namespace:WpfApplication1}MoveThumb'." (System.Xaml.XamlParseException)
A System.Xaml.XamlParseException was thrown: "Type reference cannot find type named '{clr-namespace:WpfApplication1}MoveThumb'."
Time: 2014-10-20 15:11:04
Thread:Main Thread[5916]

Comment: What is the namespace of `MoveThumb`?

Comment: Namespace is the same for everything in the whole program.

Comment: Anyone can help me with the problem?

Comment: Are you sure your `public class MoveThumb` is in a namespace. Your code works here fine, when I add the namespace to your code.